# How can I translate this python function to c++?

Tags: python, c++, c++11, recursion

I am trying to translate a python function to c++ without success. Can someone help me?

The python function receives as input a string S and 2 integers (fragment_size and jump).
The aim of this function is to slice the string S in a number of fragments of length equal to the first integer given by the input (fragment_size) and traverse the whole string S with a step equal to the second integer given by the input (jump).

```
import sys
# First we read the input and asign it to 3 different variables
S = sys.stdin.readline().strip()
fragment_size = sys.stdin.readline().strip()
jump = sys.stdin.readline().strip()

def window(S, fragment_size, jump):
    word = S[:fragment_size]
    if len(word)< fragment_size:
        return []
    else:
        return [word] + window(S[jump:], fragment_size, jump)

# We check that S is not an empty string and that fragment_size and jump are bigger than 0. 
if len(S) > 0 and int(fragment_size) > 0 and int(jump) > 0:
    # We print the results 
    for i in window(S, int(fragment_size), int(jump)):
        print(i)
```

For example:
**Input**
ACGGTAGACCT
3
1

**Output**
ACG
CGG
GGT
GTA
TAG
AGA
GAC
ACC
CCT

Example 2:
**Input**
ACGGTAGACCT
3
3

**Output**
ACG
GTA
GAC

I know how to solve this in c++ returning a string in the window function. But I really need to return a list, like the one I am returning in the python program.

Right now, I have this C++ code:

```
# include <iostream>
# include <vector>
# include <string>
using namespace std;

vector<string> window_list(string word, vector<vector<string>>& outp_list){
    outp_list.push_back(word);
}

vector<string> window(string s, int len_suf, int jump){
    string word;
    vector<vector<string>> outp_list; 

    word = s.substr(0, len_suf);
    if(word.length() < len_suf){
        return vector<string> window_list();
    }
    else {
        window_list(word, outp_list);
        return window(s.substr(jump), len_suf, jump);
    } 
}

int main(){
    // We define the variables
    string s;
    int len_suf, jump;
    // We read the input and store it to 3 different variables
    cin >> s;
    cin >> len_suf;
    cin >> jump;
    // We print the result
    vector<string> ans = window(s, len_suf, jump);
    for(auto& x: ans){
        cout << x << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us what did you try so far? Share your code.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `string` data type you can achieve it without so much problems. Instead of the python `[:]` operator, you can use the `substr` method:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

string S = "";
int fragment_size = 0;
int jump = 0;
char a_result[1024];

string window(string s) {
    if (s.length() < fragment_size)
        return "";
    else
        return s.substr(0, fragment_size) + " " + window(s.substr(jump));
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    
    cin >> S;
    cin >> fragment_size;
    cin >> jump;
    
    if (S.length() && fragment_size > 0 && jump > 0) {
        string result = window(S);
        
        cout << endl 
             << result;
        
        // Get array from the string
        strncpy(a_result, result.c_str(), sizeof(a_result));
        a_result[sizeof(a_result) - 1] = 0;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Also, in your `window` function, you have an extra for loop that isn't needed since you return a value after the first iteration.

Comment: @Lous Glad to help

Comment: is there a way to return a list instead of a string?

Comment: You can work with a string as an array like `stringname[n]`, if you want a global char array to use in all the scope you can use `strncpy` function. I will update the answer

Answer (score 0):

It does the job, but as I'm not very into C++ Alexandros Palacios approach might be better anyways. This is just a blunt translation of your Python code.

```cpp
#include <strings.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::string window(std::string S, int fragment_size, int jump) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= S.length(); jump) {
        std::string word = S.substr(i, i+fragment_size);
        if (word.length() < fragment_size) {
            return "";
        }
        else {
            return word + " " + window(S.substr(jump, S.length()-1), fragment_size, jump);
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    std::string S;
    std::cout << "Enter DNA sequence: ";
    std::cin >> S;
    int fragment_size;
    std::cout << "Enter fragment size: ";
    std::cin >> fragment_size;
    int jump;
    std::cout << "Enter jump size: ";
    std::cin >> jump;
    
    std::vector<std::string> data;
    std::string result;
    if (S.length() > 0 && fragment_size > 0 && jump > 0) {
       result = window(S, fragment_size, jump);
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
    size_t pos;
    std::string delimiter = " ";
    while ((pos = result.find(delimiter)) != std::string::npos) {
        data.push_back(result.substr(0, pos));
        result.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());
    }
    for (const auto &str : data) {
        std::cout << str << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the program shown in the [below](https://onlinegdb.com/SOsrF37B-D) example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
std::vector<std::string> stringFragmenter(const std::string &inputString, int len, int stepSize)
{
    std::string::const_iterator currentBegin = inputString.begin();
    
    std::string::const_iterator end = inputString.end();
    std::string::const_iterator currentPosition = currentBegin;
    
    std::vector<std::string> output;
    std::string pushedString;
    while(currentPosition + len <= end)
    {
        currentBegin = currentPosition;
        std::string::const_iterator currentEnd = currentBegin + len;
        
       
        
        
        while(currentBegin != currentEnd)
        {
            pushedString+= *currentBegin;
            ++currentBegin;
        }
        output.push_back(pushedString);
        
        currentPosition = currentPosition + stepSize;
        
        //clear the pushedString for next iteration
        pushedString.clear();
        
    }
    return output;
}
int main()
{
    std::string inputString;
    std::cin >> inputString;
    
    int length;//this denotes the length of string that has to be displayed(stored) at each time
    std::cin >> length;
    
    int stepSize;
    std::cin >>stepSize;//this denotes the jump size
    
    
    
    std::vector<std::string> fragmentedString = stringFragmenter(inputString, length, stepSize);
    
    //print out the elements of the returned vector so that we can confirm if it contains the correct elements
    for(const std::string &elem: fragmentedString)
    {
        std::cout<<elem<<std::endl;
    }

    
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the above program matches with both of your input cases as can be seen [here](https://onlinegdb.com/SOsrF37B-D).

In the above program, to enter your input case 1 you should first enter the string `ACGGTAGACCT` and then the length 3 and then finally the stepSize(or jump size) 1 and the input/output would look like:

```
ACGGTAGACCT
3
1
ACG
CGG
GGT
GTA
TAG
AGA
GAC
ACC
CCT
```

which matches with your desired output. Similarly for your input case 2. Check out the output [here](https://onlinegdb.com/SOsrF37B-D).